# Generating report from multiple mysql databases hosted on different servers

Tags: mysql, database, dns

I have four different servers; parent.com, a.com, b.com and c.com. At the end of the day I have to pull data and generate report from a, b and c and show in parent. a, b and c databases are having same the structure, but as I mentioned, they're hosted on different IP/server.

Can you please tell me what may be my approach?

Comment: Oracle has "database link" and SQL Server has "Linked Servers" - they allow a single instance to serve as the gateway to other database instances so your reporting only thinks it's using a single database.

Comment: then tag your question as such!

Comment: your best approach may be partly dependant on your reporting tools; for example, BIRT includes the concept of joint data sets, where data from different data sets (which can be obtained from different data sources) can be linked together. Which reporting tool(s) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does support FEDERATED tables, although performance may not be particularly great.